# How to prepare a generic shell script which can identify video files and transcode them with FFmpeg according to a few rules?

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to get a bare-bones (just running a few commands) script which should read a folder with sub-folders for video files, select the ones which are not HEVC encoded and pass them to `ffmpeg`, and after - compare the size of the input and output files and if the output is larger in size - move on to the next one, or if the size is smaller - replace the original file.

My logic goes like so:

1. Prepare plain txt list:

   ```
   find /folder -type f \( -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.avi" \) > log.txt
   ```
2. Pass the txt to `ffprobe`

   ```
   ffprobe "log.txt" -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1
   ```

This is where `ffprobe` should receive line 1,2,3, etc from `log.txt`, however I do not know how to do this, because `ffprobe` only accepts single input.

3. `ffprobe` should run the list and output the non-HEVC results in `log1.txt`
4. This is where `log1.txt` should be passed to `ffmpeg` for transcoding, using the system `/tmp` folder. I have a working `ffmpeg` command, the syntax here is not a problem for a single file.
5. Compare the input and output - if the input is larger than the output - replace it. If the output is larger than the input - discard it and move on to the next one.

The problems I have are mostly linked to passing variables (see 2.) and definetly (5.). I need some pointers as to how to approach the issues stated above, rather than a solution.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you using find to recurse into sub-directories or is this a flat hierarchy?

Comment: @Hermann - Yes - recurse in sub-directories, because most of them have varying depth.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using find for creating a list of files. [Parsing find's output it is dangerous and should be avoided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) – especially if file names with spaces are involved. It is way better to prepare a script that will to the bulk of the work and have it executed via find's exec parameter (the protected semicolon is necessary, I also used single quotes to stop wildcards to be expanded by bash rather than find):

```
find /folder -type f \( -iname '*.mkv' -o -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.avi' \) -exec transcode.sh {} \;
```

You can call ffprobe directly on the file and pipe the output to grep to check for the codec name (please note that I do not know the actual name of the codec you want, please adapt):

```
if ffprobe "$1" -hide_banner -loglevel panic -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name | grep -q 'hvec'
then
  # TODO: do transcoding
fi
```

After transcoding, you can [compare file sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108244/compare-file-sizes-in-shell-script) and act accordingly (note that I deliberately leave file stubs in place so you don't waste time and energy transcoding the file again next time you execute the script):

```
if [[ $(stat -c%s "$f") -gt $(stat -c%s "$fhvec") ]]
then
  mv "$fhvec" "$f"
else
  truncate -s 0 "$fhvec"
fi
```

And a more general warning: Do this only on data which is not important (previews, thumbnails, proxies). HVEC is a powerful encoder, but you may end up with videos containing compression artifacts from two distinct encoders. They might be small, but ugly to the eye, too.

Comment: Thanks for pointers, let me give it a go!